# Clojure: How To use-fixtures in Testing

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am writing some unit tests that interact with a database. For this reason it is useful to have a setup and a teardown method in my unit test to create and then drop the table.  However [there are no docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.test/use-fixtures) :O on the use-fixtures method.

Here is what i need to do:

```
 (setup-tests)
 (run-tests)
 (teardown-tests)
```

I am not interested currently in running a setup and teardown before and after each test, but once before a group of tests and once after.  How do you do this?

Comment: Glad to see that there are plenty of docs at that linked URL now :) and also at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use `use-fixtures` to provide setup and teardown code for freely defined groups of tests, but you can use `:once` to provide setup and teardown code for each namespace:

```
;; my/test/config.clj
(ns my.test.config)

(defn wrap-setup
  [f]
  (println "wrapping setup")
  ;; note that you generally want to run teardown-tests in a try ...
  ;; finally construct, but this is just an example
  (setup-test)
  (f)
  (teardown-test))    


;; my/package_test.clj
(ns my.package-test
  (:use clojure.test
        my.test.config))

(use-fixtures :once wrap-setup) ; wrap-setup around the whole namespace of tests. 
                                ; use :each to wrap around each individual test 
                                ; in this package.

(testing ... )
```

This approach forces some coupling between setup and teardown code and the packages the tests are in, but generally that's not a huge problem. You can always do your own manual wrapping in `testing` sections, see for example [the bottom half of this blog post](http://thornydev.blogspot.nl/2012/09/before-and-after-logic-in-clojuretest.html).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using something like this: `(defn test-ns-hook []
    (create-table)
    (put-4)
    (put-5)
    (get-2)
    (get-3)
    (get-4)
    (scan-2)
    (scan-3)
    (scan-4)
    (drop-table))`

Comment: @DavidWilliams You're not really supposed to put your tests in the wrap/hook. The whole point of fixtures is that you separate the setup code from the tests. That's what the argument (f in my example) of the hook is for; it's the callback the runs the tests (and any other hooks) at the right place in your fixture's code. Then you just define your tests as usual (with deftest, for example).

Comment: I agree that the ThornyDev blog posts is a nice summary of the use-fixtures part of clojure.test.    http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2012/09/before-and-after-logic-in-clojuretest.html

Answer (score 1):

Per the [API for clojure.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html):

> Fixtures allow you to run code before and after tests, to set up the
> context in which tests should be run.
>
> A fixture is just a function that calls another function passed as an
> argument.  It looks like this:
>
> ```
> (defn my-fixture [f]    
>   ;; Perform setup, establish bindings, whatever.   
>   (f) ;; Then call the function we were passed.    
>   ;; Tear-down / clean-up code here.  
> )
> ```

There are "each" fixtures for set-up and tear-down around individual tests, but you wrote that you want what "once" fixtures provide:

> [A] "once" fixture is only run once, around
> ALL the tests in the namespace. "once" fixtures are useful for tasks
> that only need to be performed once, like establishing database
> connections, or for time-consuming tasks.
>
> Attach "once" fixtures to the current namespace like this:
>
> ```
> (use-fixtures :once fixture1 fixture2 ...)
> ```

I'd probably write your fixture something like:

```
(use-fixtures :once (fn [f] 
                      (setup-tests)
                      (f)
                      (teardown-tests)))
```