# clojure maven plugin: clojure tests succeed when using mvn clojure:test but NOT during test phase when using mvn install

Tags: maven, clojure, maven-2, clojure-java-interop

I am using the clojure maven plugin to build a project. The projects contains a test, let us say *mytest.clj*, that has a content like the following:

```
(def ^:dynamic *server*
  (create-server "tcp://bla.bla:9999"))

(deftest blabla1...)
(deftest blabla2...)
```

If I run  ***mvn clojure:test*** , the build runs successfully.

But If I run ***mvn install***  then when the test phase is reached, the server declared in *mytest.clj* is started. After that start, nothing more happens: the clojure test script seems to be frozen and building of the project cannot be continued (without any error message): Maven just hangs. Although, as already said,  ***mvn clojure:test*** runs successfully for the same project.

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thx in advance
Regards

Horace

P.S: I can use the standard ***mvn install*** to compile and test the clojure sources because my project's packaging is configured as a 'clojure' one in *pom.xml*. The consequence of it, is that the clojure maven plugin then automatically binds itself  to the maven phases compile, test and test-compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are starting a server when the tests are run, but you are not shutting down that server when everything is finished.

You'll want to use fixtures to make sure you're killing any threads/agents/servers you start in the test.

See [Clojure: How To use-fixtures in Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350504/clojure-how-to-use-fixtures-in-testing)