# How to run Clojure code before each "lein test"?

Tags: testing, clojure, leiningen

How can I run some Clojure code before tests in test files are run?

I'd like to have some piece of Clojure code to be called either before running all the tests (say by doing `lein test` at the root of my lein project) or before running indidual tests. I don't want to duplicate that piece of code in several `.clj` files.

How can I do that? Is there some "special" `.clj` file that can be run before any test is run?

Comment: Have you tried using preconditions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: googling for *"lein test preconditions"* gives me this very SO question I just asked as the first answer :(   To answer your question: no I didn't try preconditions... But I wouldn't mind if I knew what to read / google for : )

Comment: I don't know anything about lein.  But usually test frameworks give you some way to do a setup prior to running the tests.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use test fixtures.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350504/clojure-how-to-use-fixtures-in-testing) has a good answer on it that can get you started.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes; lein is "just" a build tool. In the case of tests, all it does is put your test code on the classpath, and then run the tests. Since fixtures are provided by clojure.test, and lein does not interfere with your project code, this works with lein. Most everything does, really; the vast majority of Clojure programs are built via lein.

Comment: Using fixtures will run the code before every single test.  I find this is rarely the scenario desired.  Normally I want to run code before every integration test, but not unit tests, or something similar.  In this case, a simple macro that handles your setup and teardown works much better than fixtures.

Comment: You can have fixtures run before each test or run only once @arcdrag